# CefSharp MSI Installer Project - Unrecoverable build error - 0x8007000B

Tags: .net, windows-installer, cefsharp, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have project WinForms with .net core 3.1 and I am using in this project CefSharp.WinForms (version 89.0.170).

I upgraded to newest version:

CefSharp.Common.NETCore" Version="111.2.20"

CefSharp.WinForms.NETCore" Version="111.2.20"

When I build app in Visual Studio 2022 everything works correctly.

However, when I try to create the msi installer, I get an error:

Done building project "Tets.csproj".
------ Starting pre-build validation for project 'TestSetup' ------
WARNING: Unable to find dependency 'SYSTEM.IO.FILESYSTEM' (Signature='B03F5F7F11D50A3A' Version='4.1.2.0') of assembly 'Test.Installer.SetupActions.dll'
WARNING: Unable to find dependency 'SYSTEM.RUNTIME.EXTENSIONS' (Signature='B03F5F7F11D50A3A' Version='4.2.2.0') of assembly 'Test.Installer.SetupActions.dll'
WARNING: Unable to find dependency 'SYSTEM.RUNTIME' (Signature='B03F5F7F11D50A3A' Version='4.2.2.0') of assembly 'Test.Installer.SetupActions.dll'
WARNING: Unable to find dependency 'SYSTEM.DIAGNOSTICS.PROCESS' (Signature='B03F5F7F11D50A3A' Version='4.2.2.0') of assembly 'Test.Installer.SetupActions.dll'
WARNING: Unable to find dependency 'SYSTEM.CONSOLE' (Signature='B03F5F7F11D50A3A' Version='4.1.2.0') of assembly 'Test.Installer.SetupActions.dll'
------ Pre-build validation for project 'TestSetup' completed ------
12>------ Rebuild All started: Project: TestSetup, Configuration: Release ------
Building file '\Release\TestSetup.msi'...
ERROR: Unrecoverable build error - 0x8007000B

In version CefSharp.WinForms (version 89.0.170) works correctly.

Does anyone know how to fix this or how to check the error (logs) more precisely?

Even viewer - there is nothing

Comment: Have you set a [RuntimeIdentifier](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Quick-Start-For-MS-.Net-5.0-or-greater#20-set-a-runtimeidentifier-in-your-proj-file) as per the instructions?

Comment: @amaitland I added  RuntimeIdentifier  and it works. Thank you.